Solar charger for generic battery charging
I have 8 Ni-Mh batteries in series to power a nrf9160. In between is a regulator that steps the voltage down to 5V. The nrf9160 takes up more energy than I anticipated. So I was looking into powering it via a solar panel. But all the charging modules I found so far can only power a single type of battery. Liek a 3.7 LiPO or 1.2V NiMh. Is there a way to set an arbitrary Voltage so it can charge any (reasonable) amount of batteries that are connected in series. Aside from that I am unsure what happens on a very sunny day. All the batteries are charged to 100% but there is still energy coming in. Will a charger like this one or this one just stop charging, or will they try to put in more energy that the battery is rated for? What do I have to look for in datasheets to find out it's behavior in such a situation? If you know a combination of solar panel, charging controller and some exotic battery combination please let me know the part names.
